# how to add venue to foursquare without user authentication

Tags: addition, foursquare

I want to add venues to foursquare from my app but I don't want to make the users sign in into foursquare. I created one fake user that my server uses for all the real users of my application, but I'm afraid foursquare will block this fake user becauase it's going to add many venues, and from different places at the same time.

What's the best solution?

thanks.

Comment: I have the same question.  I would love if someone could elaborate on this.  Under what cases will foursquare allow you to create a place without authenticating the user?

Answer (score 1):

Your set up is definitely not recommended, but as a way to mitigate your risks, limit the number of venues a user can create via your app (like 1 per day). Otherwise one abusive user can cause your entire user account to be suspended.