# Can I use the same account to add multiple venues to FourSquare on the behalf of multiple users

Tags: foursquare

I am working on a social app that needs to let users add new venues to Foursquare in rare occasions. Many if not most of these users may not have a Foursquare account, and I would then like to avoid requiring them to create one just for that feature.

I've read [the related thread about Adding Venues without Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266296/how-to-add-venue-to-foursquare-without-user-authentication). Although ideal, this solution is unfortunately not accessible to us since we're a small startup.

So here's my question: could I use a single default FS account, that would be registered to my startup, to add venues on the behalf of all my users? In other words, each a time any user needs to add a venue, the app would be authenticating to FS using the same account in the background.
Would such model be allowed and supported by FS, or considered abusive?

Thanks a ton in advance for any guidance on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said adding venues is a rare occasion that should work fine. You'll be rate-limited on that single authenticated account, but it shouldn't be an issue at low volumes. I believe the default limit is 500 requests per hour per authenticated user. If you're adding more than that, you're not a small startup :)